# Is it possible to pass a character vector of variable length to R function?

Tags: r

In the function below:

```
subset_data <- function(coldata, a, b){
    coldata <- coldata[, c(a, b)]
    return(coldata)
}
```

`c(a, b)` is having only two elements, `a` and `b`. Is it possible to make it flexible so the user can pass any number of elements, i.e., to have for example `c(a, b, c, d)` or any other possibilities?

### Example of coldata

```
sample tissue species time condition
s1 liver mouse morning treated
s2 liver mouse morning treated
s3 brain fly evening untreated
```

### Usage of function

```
subset_data(coldata, d = c("tissue", "species")
```

### Desired change:

```
subset_data(coldata, d = c("tissue", "species", "time")
```

or

```
subset_data(coldata, d = c("tissue", "species", "time", "condition")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess what you need is a three dots or ellipsis construct. See [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-three-dots-ellipsis/) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do that. I think the easiest solutions involve simply to use string vectors. You could also use `...` but in your example this is an unecesseray complication. I propose you `data.table` or `dplyr` syntax :

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
subset_data <- function(data, cols = c('a','b')){
  data2 <- data.table::as.data.table(data)
  return(data2[,.SD,.SDcols = cols])
}
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
subset_data <- function(data, cols = c('a','b')){
  data %>% dplyr::select(cols)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given it seems you just want to be able select specific columns, why not use `select` from `dplyr`? E.g.

```
df = data.frame(tissue = sample(c("brain", "liver", "kidney"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                species = sample(c("mouse", "cat", "dog"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                time = sample(c("day", "evening", "night"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                condition = sample(c("dead", "alive"), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Then just select the columns you want, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(tissue, species)
```

or

```
df %>%
  select(tissue, species, time)
```